# How would a proper Rust code setup look like for database queries?

Tags: rust, idioms

I am building a rather simple application that periodically writes data into a sqlite database. My `src` folder looks like this:

```bash
.
├── constants.rs
├── database
│   ├── db.rs
│   ├── error.rs
│   ├── mod.rs
│   └── queries.rs
├── main.rs
├── types.rs
└── utils.rs
```

In `constants` is currently only the `DEFAULT_DB_PATH` `&str` stored. `database` contains the logic for the database calls. `queries.rs` contains SQL queries, like

```rust
pub const START_QUERY: &str = r"INSERT INTO fees (user_id, fee) VALUES (?1, ?2);";
```

In `error.rs` I defined my own custom errors, based on SQL results.

```rust
#[derive(Debug)]
pub enum CustomError {
    UserExistsAlready,
    QueryError,
    ...
}

impl std::error::Error for CustomError {}

impl fmt::Display for CustomError {
    fn fmt(&self, f: &mut fmt::Formatter) -> fmt::Result {
       ...
```

In `types.rs` are the database types that I try to store and retrieve. The real database calls are in `db.rs`. And here I have a lot of duplicate code that I would like to clean up.

For example I have the following function

```rust
fn get_payments_for_user(
    group_id: i64,
    user_id: u64,
    week: u32,
) -> Result<TotalPayment, CustomError> {
    let conn = get_connection();
    let mut stmt = conn.prepare(GET_TOTAL_PAYMENT_FOR_USER_PER_WEKK).unwrap();
    let mut iter = stmt
        .query_map((group_id, user_id, week), |row| {
            Ok(TotalPayment {
                group_id: row.get(0)?,
                user_id: row.get(1)?,
                week: row.get(2)?,
                amount: row.get(3)?,
            })
        })
        .unwrap();

    match iter.next() {
        Some(next) => match next {
            Ok(p) => Ok(p),
            Err(_) => Ok(TotalPayment {
                group_id: group_id,
                user_id: user_id as i64,
                week: week,
                amount: 0.0,
            }),
        },
        None => Ok(TotalPayment {
            group_id: group_id,
            user_id: user_id as i64,
            week: week,
            amount: 0.0,
        }),
    }
}
```

As you can see I already split the creation of the `sqlite` connection to the function `get_connection`. But basically every database call follows the same pattern, such that it looks really bloated.

What is a production solution to such a setup usually?

Comment: For the 2nd match you can collapse the inner match by matching on `Some(Ok(p))` and `None | Some(Err(_))`, respectively, but I'm not sure how you'd go about not repeating the construction of `TotalPayment` on the top and bottom. Maybe a constructor function could help reduce bloat?

Comment: there are multiple things that can be refactored to make this code less bloated. first thing I would advice is make a constructor that take a row for `TotalPayment`, so you can just do `.query_map((group_id, user_id, week), TotalPayment::from_row)`, then if you don't care about the error you can collapse the entire match statement with `iter.next().map(Result::ok).flatten()`, this will transform `Option<Result<T, E>>` to `Option<T>` then you can just call `Option::unwrap_or`. [playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=9933df049c20e0299a73abf0fbe39741)

Comment: but from what I'm seeing you are never creating your custom error, so you could just do something like this: [playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=2f06000615b75a83f717cdd447dd0459)

Comment: Ah great, the `from_row` constructor will reduce my bloat by quite a lot